# Custom font on iOS always uses 'regular' style

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

I'm using a custom font (BebasNeueLight). It looks like this in Font Book:
[image: Font book]
I've added it to the iOS project in the usual style; copied it into the project added a key in the plist "Fonts provided by application" and added the name of the file (`BebasNeueLight.otf`).

In my label in Swift I do the following:

```
label.font = UIFont(name: "BebasNeueLight", size: 24.0)!
```

Which is the actual Postscript name of the font.

When I run the app I see the custom font is loaded; but it displays the regular style (which I neither added to my project or specified):
[image: Simulator screenshot]
Font book screenshot with the 'regular' style:
[image]
Has anyone seen this before? I'm guessing there is something 'wrong' with the font itself. I works fine on Android btw.

-- Edit:

I'm using the correct name, I've gotten this name with fontconfig and Swift code for printing font (and it is loading the custom font; just not the correct style..). Output:

```
❯ fc-scan --format "%{postscriptname}\n" BebasNeueLight.otf
BebasNeueLight
```

--

The Storyboard also renders the font 'wrong'; I've selected the font with my label (as attributed so you can see the render preview):
[image: Font in label properties]

But the Storyboard already renders it as the 'regular' type (just as the app):
[image: Storyboard preview]

So I'm thinking it is a problem with the font itself for some reason.

Comment: the font's name not really _a_ definition of the visual appearance of actual font; how did you make sure that you are loading the right font in the iOS app?

Comment: See my edit; if I change it it either crashes (as expected with an unknown name) or still loads the custom font but always in regular style.

Comment: check font name you have applied

Comment: @DriesS can you see the correct font on storyboard ?

Comment: Actually I can't; I see the correct font in the properties (also rendered correctly but in the storyboard preview it already renders the 'regular' style. This leads me to believe there is *something* wrong with the font itself. I'll update the question with some screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest iOS SDK and Xcode (9.3) fixes this problem, so I guess it was a bug in IOS < 11.3.

Current version in which it works as expected:

```
❯ xcodebuild -showsdks
iOS SDKs:
iOS 11.3                        -sdk iphoneos11.3
```

The device also needs to be running at least iOS 11.3!

All the other setup (adding font to plist.info, using correct postscript font-name etc) was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is at font name `"BebasNeueLight"`, put below function at your app delegate and call it:

```
    func printFonts() {
        let fontFamilyNames = UIFont.familyNames
        for familyName in fontFamilyNames {
            print("------------------------------")
            print("Font Family Name = [\(familyName)]")
            let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName)
            print("Font Names = [\(names)]")
        }
    }
```

then check the name of loaded font family name may be `"BebasNeue-Light"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "BebasNeueLight" in font file name does not correspond with real font title name. So you need to find you the font name somehow. One of the variants is:

```
func listFontsNames(){
    for family : String in UIFont.familyNames as [String]
    {
        print("Family : \(family)")

        for name in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
        {
            print("name : \(name)")
        }

    }
}
```

Of course you've added font to project and to info.plist?

Comment: I've added it to the project and info.plist; and as can be seen from the simulator screenshot it is loading a custom font; just the regular version and not the light version I've specified.

Comment: This means that you need files with missed font variants

Comment: Which I think I have; I have 5 differnent files for the different variants. And as Font Book shows it includes the Light variant.

Comment: Check if all are added to project like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/ekcz9dkm535lrf6/Screenshot%202018-03-05%2014.56.57.png?dl=0 and check if all are appearing in info.plist like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/plj77gdv2b24mtk/Screenshot%202018-03-05%2014.57.44.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

you can print all fonts (see below). You can also check if the font exists.

```
for family in UIFont.familyNames {
        print("\(family)")

        for name in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family) {
            print("   \(name)") // <- FontName
        }
    }
```

copy and paste your font name from log and try to assign:

```
label.font = UIFont(name: "<PasteYourFontNameHere>", size: 24.0)!
```

sometimes the font name is different.

Answer (score 0):

1.Add font file into project

2.Add a new entry with the key **"Fonts provided by application"** in plist file 
each of your files, add the file name to this array in Fonts provided by application

3.`label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BebasNeueLight" size:15];`

Swift.

```
label.font = UIFont(name:"BebasNeueLight", size:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Did you setup everything from xcode etc? If not please follow this**

If you are using webfont then download.ttf file and drop it into your project . Check mark on copy items if needed

Next add this on info plist

```
 <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Your fontname.ttf</string>
        <string>Bakersfield Bold.ttf</string>
   </array>
```

Now take a look the font family name. Which you will find on font file also. From where you have downloaded you will get there also. Like i added font which ttf file name is : Bakersfield Bold.ttf for this fontname is : Bakersfield-Bold Thats it Happy coding.

**if you already done then follow this steps**

```
label.font = UIFont(name: "BebasNeue-Light", size: 24.0)!
```

May be here you made a mistake on font name.